# Why are data bars not showing up in this R plot?

Tags: r

I have some code to create a diverging stacked bar chart. I modified it and it runs without error. However, the plot is not as expected -- the data bars are not showing up properly in the saved plot. I am relatively new to R and am not sure how to fix this...

```
library(devtools)
library(likert)
#library(plyr)
#library(reshape2)

scale_height = knitr::opts_chunk$get('fig.height')*0.5
scale_width = knitr::opts_chunk$get('fig.width')*1.25
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.height = scale_height, fig.width = scale_width)

theme_update(legend.text = element_text(size = rel(0.7)))
theme_update(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))


title = "TITLE"

headers = c("Item", "Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree")

x_label = "Category"

data_csv_text = "Type   Strongly Disagree   Disagree    Neutral Agree   Strongly Agree
Ask weather-related questions (e.g. temperature, need umbrella) 0   0.05    0   0.3 0.65
Set alarms, events, and reminders   0   0.05    0.1 0.25    0.6
Set timers  0   0   0.2 0.4 0.4
Get alerts (e.g. doorbells, smoke alarms)   0   0   0.05    0.35    0.6
Search for information (e.g. recipes, movie times)  0   0.05    0.05    0.2 0.7
Connect to other smart devices (e.g. lights, TV, cars)  0.05    0   0.05    0.5 0.4
Video-based communication (e.g. videophone/VRS) 0   0.05    0.1 0.55    0.3
Notifications (e.g. read, delete notifications) 0   0.05    0.35    0.45    0.15
Information, Warnings (e.g. traffic, weather conditions)    0   0   0.05    0.5 0.45
Manage notes (e.g. to-do lists, shopping lists) 0   0   0.4 0.4 0.2"

location = "<REDACTED_FOR_PRIVACY>"


data = read.csv(text=data_csv_text, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
data$Type = as.factor(data$Type)
names(data) = headers
data_summary = likert(summary = data)
plot = plot(data_summary, plot.percents=TRUE, plot.percent.low=FALSE, plot.percent.high=FALSE) + xlab(x_label) + ggtitle(title)

plot$layers[[2]]$geom_params$width = 0.5
plot$layers[[3]]$geom_params$width = 0.5

cowplot::save_plot(paste(location, "plot.png", sep=""), plot,base_width=300,base_height=65, units="mm",ncol = 1, nrow = 1)
```

This produces the following plot on my machine:
[image]

---

Data

```r
# dput(data)
data <- structure(list(Item = structure(c(1L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("    Ask weather-related questions (e.g. temperature, need umbrella)", "    Connect to other smart devices (e.g. lights, TV, cars)", "    Get alerts (e.g. doorbells, smoke alarms)", "    Information, Warnings (e.g. traffic, weather conditions)", "    Manage notes (e.g. to-do lists, shopping lists)", "    Notifications (e.g. read, delete notifications)", "    Search for information (e.g. recipes, movie times)", "    Set alarms, events, and reminders", "    Set timers", "    Video-based communication (e.g. videophone/VRS)"), class = "factor"), `Strongly Disagree` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0), Disagree = c(0.05, 0.05, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.05, 0, 0), Neutral = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.35, 0.05, 0.4), Agree = c(0.3, 0.25, 0.4, 0.35, 0.2, 0.5, 0.55, 0.45, 0.5, 0.4), `Strongly Agree` = c(0.65, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.4, 0.3, 0.15, 0.45, 0.2)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your `data_csv_text` in the rendered text of your question does not include the tabs `\t`, so your code is for the uninitiated not reproducible. I edited the question (the tabs are good in the question source), created `data`, and suggested an edit that includes a much better way in R to provide data: via `dput`.

Comment: @r2evans do you mean that the rendered question did not include tabs in the code text? My apologies, thank you for fixing that! Also, thanks for your edit which works (but does not help with the plotting issue). The main reason I used this method of data entry is so I can more easily update the data by copying and pasting from a separate CSV file.

Comment: No. The rendered text of your raw data does not preserve tabs, but the underlying text (that many users cannot access like I did) *does*. The code blocks are not rendering tabs: try it yourself! Highlight the spaces between numbers and such in your string and see if you get tabs. But I already fixed it, as I said, by including the output from `dput`.

Comment: It would have been a no-issue had you copied the actual CSV, not tab-delimited, since commas tend to do much better. However ... CSVs don't show `class` of columns that might be a problem in many questions, so `dput(.)` is still a much-preferred way to provide sample data.

Answer (score 0):

...I realized that the likert summary data has to be in percentages, not decimals...

So, replacing

```
data_csv_text = "Type   Strongly Disagree   Disagree    Neutral Agree   Strongly Agree
Ask weather-related questions (e.g. temperature, need umbrella) 0   0.05    0   0.3 0.65
Set alarms, events, and reminders   0   0.05    0.1 0.25    0.6
Set timers  0   0   0.2 0.4 0.4
Get alerts (e.g. doorbells, smoke alarms)   0   0   0.05    0.35    0.6
Search for information (e.g. recipes, movie times)  0   0.05    0.05    0.2 0.7
Connect to other smart devices (e.g. lights, TV, cars)  0.05    0   0.05    0.5 0.4
Video-based communication (e.g. videophone/VRS) 0   0.05    0.1 0.55    0.3
Notifications (e.g. read, delete notifications) 0   0.05    0.35    0.45    0.15
Information, Warnings (e.g. traffic, weather conditions)    0   0   0.05    0.5 0.45
Manage notes (e.g. to-do lists, shopping lists) 0   0   0.4 0.4 0.2"
```

with

```
data_csv_text = "Type   Strongly Disagree   Disagree    Neutral Agree   Strongly Agree
Ask weather-related questions (e.g. temperature, need umbrella) 0   5   0   30  65
Set alarms, events, and reminders   0   5   10  25  60
Set timers  0   0   20  40  40
Get alerts (e.g. doorbells, smoke alarms)   0   0   5   35  60
Search for information (e.g. recipes, movie times)  0   5   5   20  70
Connect to other smart devices (e.g. lights, TV, cars)  5   0   5   50  40
Video-based communication (e.g. videophone/VRS) 0   5   10  55  30
Notifications (e.g. read, delete notifications) 0   5   35  45  15
Information, Warnings (e.g. traffic, weather conditions)    0   0   5   50  45
Manage notes (e.g. to-do lists, shopping lists) 0   0   40  40  20"
```

did the trick!

Now I get this output:
[image]